# Percentage Formula - GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: google-sheets-query

I now have a new keyboard (Thanks Ken White) 
I need the following Percentage Formula: If M7 is a percentage (eg 15%).  Then I want N7 to display 15% of the number in B7.

I've been working at this for many hours (tutorials, etc.) - it seems like it would be a simple formula, but I can't seem to break it. 
I've tried working with the following {=IF(M7*B7=0,,M7*B7)} that I copied from another formula.

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: You seem to be having an issue with YOUR KEYBOARD, because it appears that the CAPS LOCK is RANDOMLY turning itself ON AND off. You may want to REPLACE it before it GETS any WORSE, because TEXT WRITTEN like THat is DIFFICULT to read.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Google's Visualization API Query Language, but perhaps achieves the result you wanted:

```
=if(cell("type",M7)="v",B7*M7,"")
```